# Can you explain the differences between these two code snippets?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

That's my first question in this platform. If there is any fault, sorry for this. I could not understand the differences between these two code snippets. I got these errors and I could not understand the reasons.

> Dog should inherit the eat() method from Animal.
>
> beagle should be an instanceof Animal.
>
> beagle.eat() should log "nom nom nom"

```
function Animal() { }
Animal.prototype.eat = function() { console.log("nom nom nom"); };

function Dog() { }

// Only change code below this line

Dog.prototype=Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;
Dog.prototype.bark= function(){
  console.log("Woof!");
}



// Only change code above this line

let beagle = new Dog();
```

```
function Animal() { }
Animal.prototype.eat = function() { console.log("nom nom nom"); };

function Dog() { }

// Only change code below this line

Dog.prototype=Object.create(Animal.prototype);

Dog.prototype={
  constructor:Dog,
  bark:function(){
    console.log("Woof!")
  }
}


// Only change code above this line

let beagle = new Dog();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
Dog.prototype=Object.create(Animal.prototype);
```

The `Dog.prototype` object is now an empty object whose *internal prototype* points to `Animal.prototype`. (so, eg, if `Dog.prototype.eat` is referenced, the `eat` property isn't found on the empty object, so via prototypal inheritance, the interpreter looks to the internal prototype object and finds `eat` on `Animal.prototype)

That's the object you want to use. But if you do

```
Dog.prototype = {
  // object initializer...
```

Now you're assigning `Dog.prototype` to a *completely different object*. The old `Object.create(Animal.prototype);` is no longer the object at `Dog.prototype`, since its value was completely reassigned. As a result, the object at `Dog.prototype` doesn't inherit from `Animal.prototype` in the end. That's the problem with the second snippet.

If you want a concise object initializer with this sort of pattern, you can use `Object.assign`:

```js
function Animal() {}
Animal.prototype.eat = function() {
  console.log("nom nom nom");
};

function Dog() {}

// Only change code below this line

Dog.prototype = Object.assign(
  Object.create(Animal.prototype), {
    constructor: Dog,
    bark: function() {
      console.log("Woof!")
    }
  }
);


// Only change code above this line

let beagle = new Dog();
beagle.eat();
console.log(beagle instanceof Animal);
```